Scriptable object lists influencing each other?
I have 2 scriptable object inventories; one acts as the starting inventory and the other acts as the current one. I add objects to the current inventory but I set it's values to the starting inventory on start.
Issue is, when I change one inventories "guns" list, the other changes too (this only happens when both objects are referenced in the gun script, but the gun script never changes the starting inventory, only sets the normal inventory to it).
Also, this only happens to the gun lists. The ammo integers aren't affected.
This shouldn't happen probably because it also happens when playmode is disabled. Is it a Unity bug?
This is problematic because it means that if the player dies with a gun they shouldn't have on start and they respawn at the start,  they'll have the aforementioned gun
Gun script: (bit long, but the parts that matter are the resetInventory function and the Inventory object assignments)
using UnityEngine;

public class Gun : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Inventory inventory;
    public Inventory startInventory;

    public Animator gunSprite;

    public Camera cam;

    private Enemy enemy;

    private bool canShoot;
    private float timer;

    public GameObject gun;
    public float movementAmmount;
    public Vector3 oldGunPos;
    public float wobbleSpeed;
    public bool moving;

    private void Start()
    {
        enemy = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Enemy Manager").GetComponent<Enemy>();

        ResetInventory();
        inventory.playerHolding = inventory.guns.Count - 1;

        var gunPos = gun.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition;
        gunPos = Vector3.Lerp(gunPos, oldGunPos, Time.deltaTime * 5);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown("" + i))
            {
                if (i <= inventory.guns.Count)
                {
                    inventory.playerHolding = i - 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        gunSprite.runtimeAnimatorController = inventory.guns[inventory.playerHolding].anims;

        timer += Time.deltaTime;

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            Shoot();
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
        {
            Reload();
        }

        oldGunPos = GetComponent<Gun>().inventory.guns[GetComponent<Gun>().inventory.playerHolding].gunPos;
        var oldPos = transform.position;
        GunWobble(oldPos);
    }

    private void GunWobble(Vector3 oldPos)
    {
        var gunPos = gun.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition;

        if (moving)
        {
            gun.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = new Vector3(oldGunPos.x + (Mathf.Sin((-timer) * wobbleSpeed / 2) * movementAmmount), oldGunPos.y + (Mathf.Sin(timer * wobbleSpeed) * movementAmmount));
        }
        else
        {
            timer = 0;
            gun.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = Vector3.Lerp(gunPos, oldGunPos, Time.deltaTime * 5);
        }
    }

    private void Shoot()
    {
        if (canShoot)
        {
            if (inventory.guns[inventory.playerHolding].currentAmmo > 0 && timer >= inventory.guns[inventory.playerHolding].timeBetweenShots)
            {
                var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector2(Screen.height / 2, Screen.width / 2));

                RaycastHit hit;
                var bulletPath = Physics.Raycast(cam.transform.position, cam.transform.forward, out hit, inventory.guns[inventory.playerHolding].range);

                gunSprite.Play("Shoot");

                inventory.guns[inventory.playerHolding].currentAmmo--;

                if (hit.collider != null && hit.collider.tag == "Enemy")
                {
                    enemy.Hurt(int.Parse(hit.collider.name.Substring(5)) - 1, inventory.guns[inventory.playerHolding].damage, hit.point);
                }

                canShoot = false;
                timer = 0;
            } else
            {
                Reload();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Reload()
    {
        int bullet = 0;
        string bulletType = "";

        if (inventory.guns[inventory.playerHolding].bulletType == GunObject.bulletTypes.tiney)
        {
            bullet = inventory.tineyAmmo;
            bulletType = "tiney";
        } else if (inventory.guns[inventory.playerHolding].bulletType == GunObject.bulletTypes.medium)
        {
            bullet = inventory.mediumAmmo;
            bulletType = "medium";
        }
        else if(inventory.guns[inventory.playerHolding].bulletType == GunObject.bulletTypes.big)
        {
            bullet = inventory.bigAmmo;
            bulletType = "big";
        }
        else if (inventory.guns[inventory.playerHolding].bulletType == GunObject.bulletTypes.shells)
        {
            bullet = inventory.shellsAmmo;
            bulletType = "shells";
        }
        else if (inventory.guns[inventory.playerHolding].bulletType == GunObject.bulletTypes.explosive)
        {
            bullet = inventory.explosiveAmmo;
            bulletType = "explosive";
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Bullet type is not present in ammo");
        }

            gunSprite.Play("Reload");

        if (bullet >= inventory.guns[inventory.playerHolding].magCapacity)
        {
            inventory.guns[inventory.playerHolding].currentAmmo = inventory.guns[inventory.playerHolding].magCapacity;
            
            if (bulletType == "tiney")
            {
                inventory.tineyAmmo -= inventory.guns[inventory.playerHolding].magCapacity;
            } else if (bulletType == "medium")
            {
                inventory.mediumAmmo -= inventory.guns[inventory.playerHolding].magCapacity;
            }
            else if(bulletType == "big")
            {
                inventory.bigAmmo -= inventory.guns[inventory.playerHolding].magCapacity;
            } else if (bulletType == "shells")
            {
                inventory.shellsAmmo -= inventory.guns[inventory.playerHolding].magCapacity;
            }
            else if (bulletType == "explosive")
            {
                inventory.explosiveAmmo -= inventory.guns[inventory.playerHolding].magCapacity;
            }

        } else if (0 < bullet && bullet < inventory.guns[inventory.playerHolding].magCapacity)
        {
            if (bulletType == "tiney")
            {
                inventory.tineyAmmo = 0;
            }
            else if (bulletType == "medium")
            {
                inventory.tineyAmmo = 0;
            }
            else if (bulletType == "big")
            {
                inventory.tineyAmmo = 0;
            }
            else if (bulletType == "shells")
            {
                inventory.tineyAmmo = 0;
            }
            else if (bulletType == "explosive")
            {
                inventory.tineyAmmo = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    private void ResetInventory()
    {
        inventory.guns = startInventory.guns;
        inventory.tineyAmmo = startInventory.tineyAmmo;
        inventory.mediumAmmo = startInventory.mediumAmmo;
        inventory.bigAmmo = startInventory.bigAmmo;
        inventory.explosiveAmmo = startInventory.explosiveAmmo;
        inventory.shellsAmmo = startInventory.shellsAmmo;
    }
}

Inventory object:
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "Inventory", menuName = "Scriptable Objects / Inventory")]
public class Inventory : ScriptableObject
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public int tineyAmmo,
        mediumAmmo,
        bigAmmo,

        shellsAmmo,
        explosiveAmmo;

    public List<GunObject> guns;

    public int playerHolding;
}

thanks

Not a bug: You’re observing normal reference-type behavior in C#. You have two variables but they reference the same object, so operations on one variable can affect the object referenced by the other variable.
To fix: Create a separate list instance (e.g., new List<GunObject>(startInventory.guns);) so changes to “current inventory” don’t mutate “start inventory.”
Watch out: If each GunObject is also a ScriptableObject, you might need to clone them individually, or change your design so that runtime data lives in something that isn’t an asset.

An alternative, if you want to avoid allocating a new list: you can recycle the current inventory list with inventory.guns.Clear(); and inventory.guns.AddRange(startingInventory.guns);`

Where would I add that line of code?

Instead of inventory.guns = startInventory.guns;.

Your solution works, changing one no longer mutates the other. Thanks!
